# LeastSquares vs ArgMin

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

From the documentation, we learn that:

`LeastSquares[m,b]`, when `b` is a vector, is equivalent to `ArgMin[Norm[m.x-b],x]`. I am wondering whether, at the level of performances (say, at the level of convergence and speed), is there a reason to prefer one method or the other when we have to deal with large and sparse matrices and vectors (and we are solving the problem numerically). I know that the question is a bit general, but any clue is more than welcome.

**UPDATE**

Having decided to use `LeastSquare` I have a further question: is `LeastSquare` parallelizable? For example, by doing a compiled version of the function, with

`CompilationTarget -> "C" , RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable} , Parallelization -> True`

Should I expect some significative speed up?

Comment: `LeastSquares` is very much preferred for large numerical matrices (both sparse and full). It's specifically optimized that.

Comment: Thanks! just noather point: Do you know how I can force `LeastSquares` to look for real solutions only?

Comment: I suspect `LeastSquares` is just solving the normal equations (I think that's the term), which is the more efficient version of multiplying by the pseudoinverse matrix. So there is no way to place a restriction on it.

Comment: I see. @DanielLichtblau, thank you

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Oh, I very much hope that `LeastSquares` avoids the normal equations; those typically have a much larger condition number. More stable alorithms are based on QR-decomposition or SVD.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It's not solving them directly. I believe it is actually using SVD, which is slower than QR but also safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LeastSquare` seems to use MKL lib internally and is already parallelized. Run the following code and observe cpu load:

```
SeedRandom[1] ;
size = 3000 ;
m = RandomReal[{-1,1},{size,size}] ;
b = RandomReal[{-1,1},size] ;
LeastSquares[m,b] ; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Check your parallel options and compare with observed cpu load:

```
SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]
```

You will get no speed up from `Compile` if you compiling only `LeastSquares` function, it will not be compiled, there will be a call to `MainEvaluate`:

```
<<CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[Compile[{{m,_Real,2},{b,_Real,1}},LeastSquares[m,b]]]
```

To get a potential speed up, all functions inside `Compile` should be [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions).
If you have a function like `Compile[{...},code1,LeastSquares[...],code2]`, you can try to compile `code1` and `code2` separately.

You can try low level functions to replace `LeastSquares`, see `LowLevelLinearAlgebra/guide/BLASGuide` in docs. This might be helpful if your matrix have special structure, e.g. triangular. More low level function:

```
?LinearAlgebra`*`*
```

Comment: Nice answer! I will try the low level functions you suggest!

Comment: @DarioRosa, thanks, also note, both options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True` should present if your want speed up from `Compile` parallelization and compiled function invocation is in it's listable form. This is similar to do-loop parallelization in openMP.